# Kubuntu failed to display "Noto Color Emoj" Fonts

Tags: kubuntu, kde, fonts

I installed fonts "Noto Color Emoj", but it does not displayed in KDE.
[image]

When apply them to apps, the fonts are invisible.(Kubuntu 22.10

```
neofetch --stdout
---------- 
OS: Kubuntu 22.10 x86_64 
Host: MacBookPro11,1 1.0 
Kernel: 5.19.0-38-generic 
Uptime: 28 mins 
Packages: 2635 (dpkg), 13 (flatpak), 11 (snap) 
Shell: bash 5.2.2 
Resolution: 1920x1080 
DE: Plasma 5.25.5 
WM: KWin 
Theme: [Plasma], Breeze [GTK2/3] 
Icons: [Plasma], breeze-dark [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: konsole 
Terminal Font: Monaco 13 
CPU: Intel i5-4258U (4) @ 2.900GHz 
GPU: Intel Haswell-ULT
```

Comment: Do you know for sure they work with your OS and version?

Comment: Yes, OS: Kubuntu 22.10 x86_64 and I add the neofetch info @David